# file not uploading on server php

Tags: php, html

Here is my code:

```
<form class="my_form" id="my_form" method="post" action="new_client.php" target="votar" enctype="multipart/form-data">   
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="file"> </label>
        <div class="input-label-wrap">
            <input type="file" class="" value="Добавить резюме" id="fileToUpload" name="fileToUpload" form="my_form">
        </div>    
    </div>   
    <div class="btn_send">
        <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $array1[12]?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" name="send" id="send">
    </div>
</form>
```

new_client.php:

```
$rand_pref = rand(10000, 99999);
$date = getdate();
$date = $date['year'].$date['mon'].$date['mday'].$date['hours'].$date['minutes'].$date['seconds'];
$target_dir = "admin/uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . $rand_pref . "_" . $date . "_" . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$file_name = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];
$uploadOk = 1;
$fileType = strtolower(pathinfo($file_name,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    //echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
} else {
    //echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
```

Im trying to send file to server but something wrong. I cant understand why it not working. Im using linux.

UPDATE: 
just changed
uploads/
to admin/uploads/

Comment: what error do you get? try to remove value from input file

Comment: @Sfili_81 i not think, that i really know how to check error log. Remove value not helping

Comment: value is a path for your file, so you don't set in your html, please show your error

Comment: Your code work fine, make uploads directory + in php.ini file  change  this values to more size like this `upload_max_filesize = 400M
post_max_size = 400M`

Comment: @Sfili_81 where can i see an error?

Comment: @Amin.MasterkinG directory created, i try to load file what size <1mb